# Way to get index of current element in ARRAY expression?

Tags: couchbase, sql++, nosql

The [ARRAY](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/collectionops.html) expression works similar to the [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example#Parameters) method in JS in that it translates elements from one array to a new array. One thing missing from ARRAY is the ability to get the index of the current element.

For example, is there a way to do this succinctly with ARRAY in n1ql?

```
// returns [{x: 7, i: 0}, {x: 3, i: 1}]
[{x: 7}, {x: 3}].map((obj, i) => ({...obj, i}));
```

Something like this would be a nice API:

```
SELECT ARRAY OBJECT_PUT(obj, "i", i) FOR obj, i IN [{x: 7}, {x: 3}] END
```

where you can define two variables after `FOR`: the first being the current array element and the optional second variable being the current array index.

Is there a valid way to do this easily?

Comment: Please also let me know if this would be a good feature request and where I could write that up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ARRAY_POSITION() function to get the index. https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.6/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/arrayfun.html#story-h2-15

And, yes multiple FOR expressions can be used in the ARRAY construct, which can be iterated together (i.e they should be of same size).
https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.6/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/collectionops.html

For ex:

```
SELECT ARRAY {i, j} FOR i IN [10, 11, 12], j IN [0, 1, 2] END;
[
  {
    "$1": [
      {
        "i": 10,
        "j": 0
      },
      {
        "i": 11,
        "j": 1
      },
      {
        "i": 12,
        "j": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Could you generalize this solution for array expressions? For example, if the array contents are unknown, how do you know what values `j` should be?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT ARRAY {"x":v.x, "i": ARRAY_POS([{"x": 7}, {"x": 3}],v)} FOR v IN [{"x": 7}, {"x": 3}] END;

Comment: Any way to do it without repetition? In my case the array is a result of a complex expression.